# How to expect toThrow on new ES6 Obj in Jasmine

Tags: jasmine, ecmascript-6

Using Jasmine, how do I test that a constructor throws an exception when given an invalid parameter?  Given the constructor below,

```
class Obj {
    constructor(name) {
        if (!name) {
            throw new TypeError('\'name\' must be a valid, non-empty string');
        }
        this._name = name;
    }
}
exports.Obj = Obj;
```

how would I test that this:

```
var test = new Obj(null);
```

throws the expected exception?

Comment: Difference here is that the error is thrown on new and not a method invocation.  I tried just invoking the constructor on prototype but I get an "Class constructors cannot be invoked without 'new'" error.

Comment: Invoking a constructor vs calling a function makes no difference though, they are both things you call that throw exceptions. e.g. `expect(() => new Obj(null)).toThrow(new TypeError())` just like in the question I linked to.

Comment: You were absolutely right... just needed to wrap the new in a function call.  Wanna add that as an answer so I can mark it?  Or close this as a dupe?

Comment: Happy to help. I still feel like this is a dupe though.